# Unable to load ArrayList data to spinner in android

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I am parsing data from server using json. Then storing them in Arraylist and loading them in to spinner in android. But I am getting same value for all the spinner data. For example I am geting json data as following:

`[{"pricing":"500,600,700,800,900,1000"}]`

Now I am comma seperating them and adding them in arraylist like this :

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(Pricing.split(","));
for(int j=0;j<items.size();j++)
{
    r.add(items.get(i));
}
```

Then loading this arraylist in spinner. 
Here's my full code:

```
    try 
                {
                    json = new JSONArray(data);
                    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) 
                    {
                        JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(i);
                        String Pricing = obj.getString("pricing");

                        List<String> items = Arrays.asList(Pricing.split(","));
                        List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for(int j=0;j<items.size();j++)
                        {
                            r.add(items.get(i));
                        }
                    }

                    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
                    ArrayAdapter cd = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,r);  
                    cd.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
                    spin2.setAdapter(cd); 
}
```

But spinner has `500  500  500  500  500  500` instead of  `500  600  700  800  900  1000`.
Anything wrong I'm doing in this code..?? I'm new to android. Please suggest me solution.

Comment: use j instead i like : r.add(items.get(j));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

You are using wrong index variable (i) which is for outer loop but your data accessing using inner loop so just replace (i) index variable with (j) index variable.

```
r.add(items.get(i));
```

**Replace**

```
r.add(items.get(j));
```

Comment: @user3519241,Good luck but please care next time for such mistake.

Comment: @user3519241,Please accept any user ans which give you first hint to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to add same value in your list,i.e. Adding **0th** value in whole list because index `i` is for json array and your right index will be `j`.

So change

```
 r.add(items.get(i));
```

to

```
 r.add(items.get(j));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change below code:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(Pricing.split(","));
                        List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for(int j=0;j<items.size();j++)
                        {
                            r.add(items.get(i));
                        }
```

via

```
 List<String> items = Arrays.asList(Pricing.split(","));
                        List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for(int j=0;j<items.size();j++)
                        {
                            r.add(items.get(j));
                        }
```

because u use i instead of j.

Comment: Hope this may help you!